# foundation joyride - how can I send a close event?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I would like to be able to shut down a running joyride using jQuery. In order to find out if it's currently running on a form I'm just checking if the joyride-tip-guide class is found on the page. However I'm not sure how to close it using code. I'm using version 4.3.2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just doing $("#joyrideID").foundation('joyride', 'hide'); seems to do the trick.